# Analog of TestNG Reporter.getOutput() in Spock

Tags: testing, logging, automated-tests, spock

I run API tests using Groovy and Spock.
Request/response data, produced by third-party libraries, appear in the system out (I see it in the Jenkins log).

**Question:** 
what is the proper way to start-stop system out recording for each test iteration to some list of strings?

TestNG has Reporter.getOutput(result) which returns all log entries, appeared while test iteration run. 
Is it something similar in Spock?

Am I right assuming it should be some implementation of [Run listener](http://org.spockframework.runtime.AbstractRunListener) where I start recording in `beforeIteration()` and attach it to report in `afterIteration`()?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand because you only use prose and I see not sample code and/or sample logs. But it sounds like you are making a simple thing complicated. Either make your test fetch a logger and use it for output or, if the application under test directly logs to stdOut/stdErr, just reroute them to a mock via `System.setOut()` and check your interactions on it if you want to test that something was logged. I have to speculate because like so many users here you do not provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), falsely believing that your explanation is clear enough.

Comment: I beg your pardon. You're correct, the application logs directly to `System.out` so I used my implementation of `Output Stream` which logs in both initial `out` and my `copy` stream object. The `copy` gets cleared in `beforeIteration()` and is attached to the report in `afterIteration()` in RunListener, so each test receiver its own part of output.

Comment: Does that mean you solved your own problem already or you need more help? If you solved your problem, it would be nice to describe your solution in more detail in an answer here for everyone's benefit. That way you could (a) accept your own solution in order to close the question and (b) return something to the community you asked for help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the [OutputCapture](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/OutputCapture.html) from 
[spring-boot-starter-test](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.3.0.RELEASE)

The sample of RunListener:

```
class RunListener extends AbstractRunListener {

    OutputCapture outputCapture

    void beforeSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
        Helper.log "[BEFORE SPEC]: ${spec.name}"
        outputCapture = new OutputCapture()
        outputCapture.captureOutput() //register a copy off system.out, system.err streams
    }

    void beforeFeature(FeatureInfo feature) {
        Helper.log "[BEFORE FEATURE]: ${feature.name}", 2
    }

    void beforeIteration(IterationInfo iteration) {
        outputCapture.reset() //clear the stream copy before each test iteration 
    }

    void afterIteration(IterationInfo iteration) {
    }

    void error(ErrorInfo error) {
        //attach the content of copy stream object to the report if  test iteration failed
        Allure.addAttachment("${error.method.iteration.name}_console_out", "text/html", outputCapture.toString(), "txt") 

    }

    void afterFeature(FeatureInfo feature) {
    }

    void afterSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
        outputCapture.releaseOutput()
    }
}
```

Shortly:

CaptureOutput is an implementation of Output Stream which logs in both initial out and  copy stream object. The copy gets cleared in `beforeIteration()` and is attached to the report in `afterIteration()` in `RunListener`, so each test receives its own part of output.